# Function to replace text in DOM

Tags: jquery

hello it's working but code is rly strange...  Really sorry for this newbie codes.

http://www.direction-code.pl/nowosci.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".leftdata li").click(function() {
  if($(this).is('.leftdata li:nth-child(1)')) {
    $(".textingc span").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Update #1 25.01.2016 2:57.");
    $(".textingc p").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Co jeszcze będzie nowego w następnym update?");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(1)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Zmiana całego layoutu.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(2)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Dodanie interaktywnej nawigacji.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(3)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Dodanie interaktywnego paska z boku.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(4)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Dodanie zakładek na wieści o updatach.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(5)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Linkująca nawigacja i pasek z boku.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(6)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Możliwość przechodzenia między zakładki update.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(7)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Możliwość przechodzenia między zakładki update.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(8)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Stworzenie podstrony kontakt.");
    $(".textingc li:nth-child(8)").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Dodanie paru animacji.");
    $(".textingc img").hide().fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    if($(this).is('.leftdata li:nth-child(2)')) {
      $(".textingc span").hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Update #2");
      $(".textingc p").html("test");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(1)").html("test");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(2)").html("tsrrest");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(3)").html("tessst");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(4)").html("tessst");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(5)").html("tessst");
      $(".textingc li:nth-child(6)").html("tessst");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  }


}); // koniec click


}); //
```

I'm sure it should be better way...

Comment: The queastion is a little confusing on what you are actually wanting to accomplish. I do not see. for example, a class name you are trying to select by ".leftdata" anywhere. Are you wishing to, when you clikc on a list item that is the first in the index of the ul, it updates the text in the paragraph tag <p>?

Comment: For example when  i click to this button it should change : <p> w tym miejscu </p> = <p> something new </p>  <ul>
      <li>Dodanka strona nowości.</li> = <li> something new </li>
      <li>Dodakkne tło</li> = <li> something new </li>
      <li>Dodanykk naglowek</li> = <li> something new </li>
    </ul>

Comment: I think I see what you need. Let me create a fiddle.

Comment: I did not use a button, and just saw that message. Just change the click event to the button identifier. I will update if or you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make it to where if you click on the li that is li:index=0, then update the paragraph, here is  the code with a working jsfiddle. I may be thinking what you want incorrectly though,a nd if so, my apologies.

A working fiddle is found here:https://jsfiddle.net/unix102/4k8yuf8k/7/

```
<div class="textingc">
```

W tym miejsckkk

```
Nowości
<ul>
  <li>Dodanka strona nowości.</li>
  <li>Dodakkne tło</li>
  <li>Dodanykk naglowek</li>
</ul>
Co planuję ?
<ul>
  <li>Stworzenie kolejnych podstron</li>
  <li>Lepsze tło</li>
  <li>Wykonanie interaktywnej nawigacji</li>
</ul>
Ostatni wpis 3:38 Niedziela. Pozdrawiam. Działa tylko jedno zmienianie tła.
```

```
$("li").click(function() {


var $li = $(this);
  var isFirstLiItem = $li.index() == 0 ? true : false;

  if(isFirstLiItem){
    $(".textingc").find("p").text($li.html());

  } else {
    return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: I added a different function to another fiddle. Let me know if this is what you needed. You click the button, and every time you click the button, it takes all the first LI items, and appends their text to the <p> tag. If not, you should be able to use one of the two examples, to acomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this code , I gonna sleep now and i will test it tommorow . I have to understand this code cuz i'm coding in jquery 2 days only :(.